# Transiting through Netherlands in private vehicle during Covid restrictions

Tags: transit, netherlands, ferries, covid-19

My family and I are German citizens and residents.  We plan in July 2021 to travel from the UK to Germany in our private car and our preferred route is to take the overnight ferry from Newcastle to IJmuiden, Netherlands and then continue in our private car to Germany.

I have read the Dutch government website regarding the current COVID-19 restrictions https://www.government.nl/topics/coronavirus-covid-19/visiting-the-netherlands-from-abroad and I want to be sure that I have understood it correctly.  Because most of the rules are for people ending or starting their journey in the Netherlands, but we will just transit in a private vehicle.

As I understand it we are allowed to arrive by Ferry and transit through NL in a car as we are EU citizens & residents.  But we will be required to provide a negative PCR test prior to embarkation in Newcastle (does this also apply to our 6-year-old?), and of course follow the restrictions related to Covid.

We plan to just transit through the country without any stops.

And I understand that we will have to quarantine upon arrival at home in Germany for 2 weeks due to current restrictions on arrivals from the UK.

Both my wife and I will have been vaccinated twice prior to the start of the trip, but as far as I can see this does not change any of the requirements above.

And of course, the situation may change!

Comment: Be extra wary, the ferry port in Tyne and Wear is not in Newcastle, it is in North Tyneside. An area under special measures with the Indian variant.

Answer (score 5):

Transit or destination doesn't really matter much. If you say need to get gas or stop for food along the way, or your car breaks down and you need to call roadside assistance you're still going to be in contact with other people.

It's also impossible to police whether you're just transiting or stop along the way of course.

So yes, the same regulations apply for everyone, and the Netherlands doesn't have any way to check your UK vaccination status so there are no excemptions from the requirement to have a valid pcr test from a recognised testing agency.
Tests are required only for children age 13 and over, so not for your 6 year old.

https://www.government.nl/topics/coronavirus-covid-19/visiting-the-netherlands-from-abroad/mandatory-negative-test-results-and-declaration

https://www.government.nl/topics/coronavirus-covid-19/visiting-the-netherlands-from-abroad/mandatory-negative-test-results-and-declaration/requirements-pcr-test-result

Comment: Why are tests only required for 13-and-overs?  Young kids with CoViD-19 are perfectly capable of infecting others.

Comment: @Vikki according to Dutch government guidelines regarding covid, children under 13 can't get infected. Yes, everyone knows it's utter BS but that was used as the reason to reopen primary schools and they're not going to admit they were wrong just because they were wrong.